# swift 3 stride cannot invoke

Tags: swift, stride

```
var arr: [Double] = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 11, by: 1.0))
```

This code is ok,
but if I write this, "cannot invoke" problem appears

```
var s = 11
var arr: [Double] = Array(stride(from: 0, through: s, by: 1.0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your `stride` statement to produce `Double`, the values passed to `from`, `through` and `by` must be `Double`s.

In the first case, Swift infers the literals `0` and `11` to be `Double`s since `1.0` is a `Double` and that is the only way they can match.  This works because `Double` conforms to the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol which just means that you can initialize a `Double` with an integer literal and an integer literal can be inferred to be a `Double` if necessary.

In the second case, you have assigned `11` to `s` and Swift assigns `s` the type `Int`.  So when you try to use that in the `stride` statement, the types don't match.

You can fix this in a number of ways:

1. Declare `s` to be a `Double` with **`var s: Double = 11`**.  In this case, you've explicitly assigned the type of `s`, so Swift uses the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` conformance of `Double` to initialize `s`.
2. Declare that `11` is a `Double` with **`var s = 11 as Double`**.  Here you have told Swift that `11` is a `Double` which works because `Double` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`.  Swift then infers the type of `s` to also be `Double`.
3. Convert `11` to a `Double` with **`var s = Double(11)`**.  This uses an initializer of `Double` that takes an `Int` as input.  Swift then infers the type of `s` to be `Double` from the value assigned to it.
4. Convert `s` when you use it with **`Double(s)`**.  Here you are explicitly using the `Double` initializer to create a `Double` with the `Int` `s`.
5. Declare `s` with a `Double` literal with **`var s = 11.0`**.  Here, Swift infers the literal `11.0` to be of type `Double` and then infers the type of `s` to also be a `Double` since it is initialized by a `Double`.